# Google visualisation with Chartrangeslider and data import from Google docs spreadsheet

Tags: charts, google-visualization, visualization

I have the problem, that I dont manage to implement my data from a google spread sheet when using dashboard environment with chartwrapper and controlwrapper. I used the piechart example from the google charts website (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls) and tried to modify without success. Maybe somebody can provide a pointer ! Thanks in advance (link to jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Chriseif/08mk90hu/1/#&togetherjs=MHq11Kn3hl)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'controls']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

     // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates a dashboard, a range slider and a pie chart,
      // passes in the data and draws it.
      function drawDashboard() {

                var query = new 



  google.visualization.Query("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/
1uJNf8RgPjcjm3pUWig0VL4EEww1PG-bNL8mtcxI6SYI/edit");
            query.send(response);

        function handleQueryResponse(response) {
                if (response.isError()) {
                     alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' 
+ response.getDetailedMessage());
                    return;
                    }
                var data1 = response.getDataTable();
            }


        // Create a dashboard.
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

        // Create a range slider, passing some options
        var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'filter_div',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnIndex ': 2
          }
        });

        // Create a pie chart, passing some options
        var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'LineChart',
          'containerId': 'chart_div',
          'options': {
            'width': 900,
            'height': 300,
            'pieSliceText': 'value',
            'legend': 'right'
           }
        });

         // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 
'pieChart',
         // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let 
through
         // given the chosen slider range.
         dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, pieChart);

        // Draw the dashboard.
        dashboard.draw(data1);
      }
     </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the dashboard-->
    <div id="dashboard_div">
      <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
      <div id="filter_div"></div>
      <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, the `query.send` method is asynchronous, and accepts an argument for a callback function
because you need to wait for the data from the query,
all of the dashboard code should be inside the callback
else it will run before the data is returned...

```
// the argument should be the name of a function
query.send(handleQueryResponse);

// callback function to be called when data is ready
function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  //draw dashboard here...
```

---

next, the range filter should operate on the column used for the x-axis
unless you are using a view, it will be column index `0` (zero is the first index)

```
var rangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
  containerId: 'filter_div',
  options: {
    filterColumnIndex: 0  // <-- x-axis column
  }
});
```

---

also, when drawing charts from a spreadsheet,
you need to set a specific number format on each axis,
otherwise, it will display the word `general` as part of the number...

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  chartType: 'LineChart',
  containerId: 'chart_div',
  options: {
    width: 900,
    height: 300,
    pieSliceText: 'value',
    legend: 'right',

    // set number formats
    hAxis: {
      format: '#,##0'
    },
    vAxis: {
      format: '#,##0'
    }
  }
});
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['corechart', 'controls']
}).then(function () {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uJNf8RgPjcjm3pUWig0VL4EEww1PG-bNL8mtcxI6SYI/edit");
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);

  function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
      alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
      return;
    }
    var data1 = response.getDataTable();

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
      document.getElementById('dashboard_div')
    );

    var rangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
      containerId: 'filter_div',
      options: {
        filterColumnIndex: 0
      }
    });

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'LineChart',
      containerId: 'chart_div',
      options: {
        width: 900,
        height: 300,
        pieSliceText: 'value',
        legend: 'right',
        hAxis: {
          format: '#,##0'
        },
        vAxis: {
          format: '#,##0'
        }
      }
    });

    dashboard.bind(rangeSlider, chart);
    dashboard.draw(data1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">
  <div id="filter_div"></div>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted to do  :)